# A string of consecutive check boxes in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to create a number of consecutive checkboxes [X] with labels in pyqt5.  Most of the similar questions I have found an online deal with aligning the checkboxes in a grid.  I don't want that.  I just want them side by side with a little descriptive text in between.

I suspect this is very easy to do, but this is my first attempt to make a simple GUI so I don't really know what I'm doing.  Ideally, I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

Heading_text

[X] text1, [X] text2, [X] text3, [X] text4
[OK]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
       self.checkBoxA   = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("text1")
       self.checkBoxB   = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("text2")
       self.checkBoxC   = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("text3")
       self.checkBoxD   = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("text4")
       self.checkboxes = [self.checkBoxA, self.checkBoxB, self.checkBoxC, self.checkBoxD]

       for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
            # print checkboxes in a list....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [`QHBoxLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html):

```py
self.checkboxes = [self.checkBoxA, self.checkBoxB, self.checkBoxC, self.checkBoxD]

lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

for checkbox in self.checkboxes:
    lay.addWidget(checkbox)
lay.addStretch()
```

Comment: dont forget `self.setLayout(lay)`

Comment: @Jonas It is not necessary if you pass the widget when you build the layout, in my code I have passed the "self" in the construction of the layout.

Comment: This sort of worked for me, but the checkboxes get further apart from one another when you expand the window they are in.  This to me feels like grid with a single row.

Comment: That does it.  Thanks a lot!